# Formatting Text and Fonts in UIViewControllers Output

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am building an application that provides and answer in swift, I was wondering if there was a way to output text to a view controller in an iOS application that would keep the formatting of swift language. I know I can format the strings manually on the output label in code, but this seems very tedious as that I have several questions. Here is an example of a question.

**Example:**

ViewController 1 Would Show:

```
Question: Create a Function that takes two paramaters x,y, and return the output of multiplying x and y together.
```

ViewController 2 Would Show:

**Answer:**

```
func(x:Int, y:Int) -> Int{
   return x * y
}
```

Currently the output for the answer is on ViewController 2 is a UITextLabel. Any thoughts and or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `keep the formatting of swift language` You want syntax highlighting, or just a multiline text view?

Comment: both if possible. The highlighting of the keywords would be nice, but mainly the multi line text view, with the formatting for the indentations etc.